# How can I redownload music from iTunes

Tags: itunes, music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to redownload songs you've paid for on iTunes?](https://superuser.com/questions/16659/is-it-possible-to-redownload-songs-youve-paid-for-on-itunes)

I had to get a new computer and my music didn't transfer over.   I have purchased some albums from iTunes and would like to be able to redownload them but am not sure how to do that.   How can I redownload an album from iTune that I had purchased in another computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can not](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1469?viewlocale=en_US), at least not without a lot of fighting with Apple ([Link](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=11029216#11029216), [Link](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa;jsessionid=FBBF5E90D24703E59803872653551798.node0?messageID=11497119&#11497119)).  You will need to transfer the files from the old computer.  Its also a good idea to have a [good backup](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/the-complete-guide-to-backing-up-your-itunes-library) of your iTunes purchases.

Oh, and Probably a duplicate of: [Is it possible to redownload songs you've paid for on iTunes?](https://superuser.com/questions/16659/is-it-possible-to-redownload-songs-youve-paid-for-on-itunes)

Comment: Nice answer. +1 for you.